# windows 8.1 c# get a element's data in gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, gridview

Bassicly, I have a datatemplate of a gridview:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BookDataTemplate">
       <Grid Width="300" Margin="0,0,40,30">
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Image Source="{Binding Img}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
       <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding BName}" x:Name="abc" /> //right here
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" />
       </StackPanel>
       </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now, my problem is how to get the **abc.text**?
Thank you for reading this!

Comment: where do you want abc.text to be used?

Comment: i want to pass it into another page.

Comment: `abc.Text ` is same as `BName` that you are binding to, u can use that value.

Comment: if I have 3 datatemplate, how do I know which one that I chosed?

Comment: you can bind it in a list with book objects in it with a bool value is clicked or something else then you have this list in all pages